# Weeks() not working as expected in FluentScheduler

Tags: c#, fluentscheduler

I'm setting up a job to run every Monday at 10 am:

```
registry.Schedule(() => new MyJob()).ToRunEvery(0).Weeks().On(DayOfWeek.Monday).At(10,0);
```

However he apparently runs the first time and doesn't run anymore.

Am I doing the job setup correctly or is there a problem with this functionality? Can you help me?

Comment: Your code looks pretty much like the code in the documentation except their job implements `IJob`. What does `MyJob` look like? Does it do all its work when instantiated?

Comment: It abstracts with a generic name just so as not to expose the functionality due to the customer.
I am currently testing a script on the console in order to validate the scheduling recurrences.

When I use Days() or Hours() ... the calls work normally.